# Why is the scanner reading before the output?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to do something in java and I need the output to be printed before the scanner reads new line from the console, but for some reason the output only comes after all scanning calls, I would like to know why is that?

I've tried to solve the problem before by using Thread.sleep() but it didnt work out.

This is the class where the function is located:

```
public class librarySystem {

    private ArrayList<Student> students;
    private ArrayList<Book> books;
    private ArrayList<RentActivity> rents;

    public void addStudent() {
        System.out.print("Enter studnet ID: ");
        String studentID = LibProject.LibProjectMain.scanner.nextLine();
        if(!ParameterUtils.validId(studentID)) {
            System.err.println("Invalid student ID.");
            return;
        }
        if(ListUtils.containsStudentByID(students, studentID)) {
            System.err.println("Student ID already exists in the system.");
            return;
        }
        System.out.print("Enter first name: ");
        String firstName = LibProject.LibProjectMain.scanner.nextLine();
        if(!ParameterUtils.validPersonName(firstName)) {
            System.err.println("Invalid first name.");
            return;
        }
        System.out.print("Enter last name: ");
        String lastName = LibProject.LibProjectMain.scanner.nextLine();
        if(!ParameterUtils.validPersonName(lastName)) {
            System.err.println("Invalid last name.");
            return;
        }
        System.out.print("Enter student email: ");
        String email = LibProject.LibProjectMain.scanner.nextLine();
        if(!ParameterUtils.validEmail(email)) {
            System.err.println("Invalid email.");
            return;
        }
        Student student = new Student(studentID,firstName,lastName,email);
        this.students.add(student);
        FileUtils.writeStudent(student);
        System.out.println(firstName + " " + lastName + " added successfully to the system.");
    }
}
```

And this is the main class, where both the main function and the scanner are located:

```
public class LibProjectMain {
    
    public static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        LibrarySystem LS = new LibrarySystem();
        boolean keepGoing = true;
        LS.addStudent();
    }
}
```

This is the expected output:

```
Enter Student ID: 123456789
Enter first name: Bob
Enter last name: Freeman
Enter student email: bobfreeman@mail.com
Bob Freeman added successfully to the system.
```

The true output:

```
123456789
Bob
Freeman
bobfreeman@mail.com
Enter studnet ID: Enter first name: Enter last name: Enter student email: Bob Freeman added successfully to the system.
```

Comment: Possibly the output stream is buffered and you need to flush it...?

Comment: You should probably be using [`Console.readLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readLine(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.out` PrintStream is flushed automatically on `println` method or if `\n` is written. If you want to use `System.out.print` without writing `\n`, consider using `System.out.flush` method:

```
System.out.print("Enter student ID: ");
System.out.flush();
String studentID = LibProject.LibProjectMain.scanner.nextLine();
```

More info on this topic can be found in [PrintStream java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html)